# Living and working in Turkey and working remotely for a University in Germany

Tags: contract-law, tax-law, germany

I'm an EU citizen, living and working full time in Turkey. Now, there is a possibility that I could also work remotely for a University in Germany. My question is: Should I pay taxes in Germany for my second job? Has anyone had any experience with how this stuff is handled by the HR departments in Germany?

Comment: As a  rule of thumb, you pay taxes where you actually perform the work. I haven't read the German–Turkish tax treaty so I won't write an answer, but it would be very unusual in your scenario if you could elect to pay taxes in Germany without living or working there. However, unless you act as a (self-employed) freelancer, it is going to be quite unlikely that the German uni can hire you. Even if a professor wants to employ you, they'll likely get shot down by HR.

Comment: "Where you actually work" is a bit vague - it could be argued that you "actually" work in Germany. But it's literally where your body is that counts. Your body is in Turkey, you pay tax in Turkey (unless Turkey has different laws).

Comment: What is the contractual relationship with the university? I don't believe that a university administration would accept the proposed "work remotely" from Turkey for an employee if this situation is full-time and permanent. So, maybe you wouldn't be an employee?